# Drag and Drop get table row id

Tags: php, jquery, drag-and-drop

I have a tables with sub tables ,And here is [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shythya/94mLp76s/21/) Now When i drag and drop sub table rows I got

```
$('.row_position>tr').each(function() {    
    selectedData.push({'id':i,'key':$(this).attr("name")});
    i++;
});
```

Under Department IT I have two sub items Backlog,and WIP so when I drag and drop I except  `selectedData.push` have two value but instead of two I got

```
[
    {"id":1,"key":"11"},
    {"id":2,"key":"10"},
    {"id":3,"key":"12"},
    {"id":4,"key":"13"}
]
```

I except

```
[
    {"id":1,"key":"11"},
    {"id":2,"key":"10"}
]
```

Again   `console.log(JSON.stringify(selectedData));` I can't get in ajax url.Please help me

Comment: You are getting 4 results because there are two `.row_position` tables which contains sub table have 2 rows. And It says '404 not found' in your ajax url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have chnaged $('.row_position>tr').each(function()  to $(this).find('tr').each(function() so you will get data of only current sub table

and for ajax URL you need to put your full actual URL in function updateOrder

```js
$( ".row_position" ).sortable({ 
        delay: 150,
        stop: function(th) {
          // var par = th.parent();
      //     console.log(JSON.stringify(th));
            var selectedData = new Array();
            var i=1;

            $(this).find('tr').each(function() {
                selectedData.push({'id':i,'key':$(this).attr("name")});
                i++;
            });
            console.log(JSON.stringify(selectedData));
            updateOrder(selectedData);
        }
    });
```

Comment: use var ajaxurl = 'your actual url' and url:ajaxurl in ajax call